# Extract data frame by its name in a list

Tags: r

I try to extract by name a `data.frame` (named `map_dist_ssp126`) which is in a `list` (named `map`) with two others dataframes, for this I have always run this

```
k <- "ssp126"
grep(k, names(map), value = TRUE)
[1] "map_dist_ssp126"
mget(grep(k, names(map), value = TRUE))
```

However, this time I have an error message, impossible to know why

```
Error: value for ‘map_dist_ssp126’ not found
```

Maybe someone has an idea? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the map_dist_ssp126 is a list element, just extract (`[[`) from its object

```
map[[grep(k, names(map), value = TRUE)]]
```